# How to choose an option in jquery without value?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to make the select option, just go ahead

```js
  $('.test1').eq(0).val('3');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="test1">
  <option href='1'>1</option>
  <option href='2'>2</option>
  <option href='3'>3</option>
  <option href='4'>4</option>
  <option href='5'>5</option>
</select>
```

So automatically, directly into the selected option **3**
But what if that value is not a number. But the letter. So, by looking at the numbers on `href` option only, not through `value`. Like this:

```html
<select class="test2">
  <option href='1'>A</option>
  <option href='2'>B</option>
  <option href='3'>C</option>
  <option href='4'>D</option>
  <option href='5'>E</option>
</select>
```

How to get the value of **C**?

This my test https://jsfiddle.net/apycb97q/

Comment: yours option tags are wrong, you need to define a value for each, the later you can select it by $(select).val("optionValue")

Comment: `href`? Please do some research before asking questions on Stack Overflow. A look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) would tell you what's up.

Comment: That's invalid HTML?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `value` attribute in your option tags:

```
<select class="test1">
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
</select>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test1').val('3'); // set a value in your dropdown
    $('.test1').val(); // get the value selected in your dropdown
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

By value, what worked for me with jQuery 1.7 was the below code, try this:

```
<select id="test1">
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
</select>

$('#test1 option[value=theOptionValue]').prop('selected', 'selected').change();
```